# How to use Request in Class PHP

Tags: php

I'm try to call request from web but not working , this code call command game server from website.

```
class SampRconAPI
{

private $command;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->command = $_REQUEST["command"];
}

if($this->command == "cmdlist")
{
    $aCommands = $this->packetSend('cmdlist');
    unset($aCommands[0]);

    foreach($aCommands as &$sCommand)
    {
        $sCommand = trim($sCommand);
    }

    return $aCommands;
}
```

My Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: command
>
> Filename: include/SampRcon.php
>
> Line Number: 7

Comment: If you want to access data passing by GET/POST than you can use $_REQUEST to get that value.

Comment: yes , but i'm call request from my website it's not working . It show error

Comment: how you are creating object of this class?

Comment: Can you please post the result of print_r($_REQUEST) here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite below line:

```
 $this->command = $_REQUEST["command"];
```

something like this:

```
 $this->command = isset($_REQUEST["command"]) ? $_REQUEST["command"] : "";
```

So that it won't give you error.

Answer (score 0):

your error made couldn't  found **command** pram on GET request . first check you service configuration is  ok .

```
 <?php
$rcon = new SampRconAPI('server_ip', server_port, 'server_rcon_pass'); 
$rcon->Call('name ' . $playerid_here);


print_r( $rcon->getInfo());
```

http://forum.sa-mp.com/showthread.php?t=104299

here is example https://gist.github.com/Westie/234209
?>